# Call a variable inside if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a quick question on how to call variables inside an if/else statement of a function. My thought looks like this.

```
var variable = {
    anything
}

var variable2 = {
    anything
}

var options = function () {
    if($(this).hasClass(".itemname")){
        return variable
    } else {
        return variable2
    }
};

$("#items li").click(options);
```

Comment: I guess that should work. What's the issue?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Oh and by the way, what are you trying to do? Returning an object in a jQuery handler is pointless.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  "I have a quick question".  So, what's the question?

Comment: I am learning javascript as I go along and I ran into this problem when using it with a specific jquery plugin and it wasn't able to work. I am guessing the problem has to do more with the plugin then with the logic itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you ask for something like this:

```
var variable = function () {
    alert(1);
}

var variable2 = function () {
    alert(2);
}

var options = function () {
    if($(this).hasClass("itemname")){
        return variable();
    } else {
        return variable2();
    }
};

$("#items li").click(options);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pd3FV/